# Perform click on an element from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, click

How can I perform click from code behind in c# on this link:

```
<a href="#close" title="Close" id="link_chiudi" class="close" runat="server"></a>
```

by `id = "link_chiudi"`?

Comment: Why not use `asp:HyperLink`?

Comment: what is your technology?asp.net webform or asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1):

By adding `onServerClick`:

```
<a href="#close" title="Close" id="link_chiudi" class="close" runat="server" onServerClick="link_chiudi_OnServerClick"></a>

protected void link_chiudi_OnServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Or:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     link_chiudi.ServerClick += link_chiudi_ServerClick;
}

void link_chiudi_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

But I recommend you that use [`LinkButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) because it is an ASP.Net server side control:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_OnClick">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Or:

```
LinkButton1.Click += LinkButton1_Click;
```